# How to prevent fuel cell gas leak?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

My research is fuel cell. I need to do a open system fuel cell, but in cathode side always have gas leak. Have any one have experience to tell me, how to prevent gas leak?

Comment: What gas is leaking?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's the cathode where the leak is I presume it's the hydrogen you can't hold. Hydrogen is very hard to contain because of it's small molecules. I use plastic glass as its bubbler and a small hose to move it elsewhere. If it's your bubbler where the leakage is insulate it using silicon around the connections/openings.